# How to use EntityManager#merge with detached Entity created using EntityGraph?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

This example shows a `User` object.

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class User
{
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="user")
    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() { return this.userRoles; }
    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) { this.userRoles = userRoles; }
}    

@javax.persistence.Entity
public class UserRole
{
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "roleid", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Role getRole() { return this.role; }
    public void setRole(Role role) { this.role = role; }
}
```

The roles are retrieved by using an `EntityGraph` in order to avoid throwing a `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`.

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class SomeService
{
    @PersistenceContext EntityManager em;
    ...
    public void blah()
    {
        EntityGraph<User> userEntityGraph = em.createEntityGraph(User.class);
        Subgraph<UserRole> userRolesSubgraph = userEntityGraph.addSubgraph("userRoles");
        userRolesSubgraph.addAttributeNodes(UserRole_.role);

        TypedQuery<User> query = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByEmail", User.class)
            .setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", userEntityGraph)
            .setParameter("email", "foo@bar.com");
        User user = query.getSingleResult();

        user.getUserRoles().iterator().next().getRole(); // Sweet!  Gets the role.
    }
}
```

The `User` object will be detached and made available to the user's login session.  Eventually the `User` may need to be merged, for example, if the user needs to change it's email.

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class SomeOtherService
{
    @PersistenceContext EntityManager em;

    ...

    public User updateEmail(User user, String email)
    {
        user.setEmail(email);
        User userNewVersion = em.merge(user);
        userNewVersion.getUserRoles(); // Sweet! Gets the userRoles.
        userNewVersion.getUserRoles().iterator().next().getRole(); // Throws org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException
        return userNewVersion;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately an `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` is thrown, so apparently the entity graph configuration no longer exists. How disappointing that the JPA API doesn't provide a means to reintroduce the entity graph configuration when a merge takes place. Is there a way to reintroduce the configuration?  Perhaps I'm missing something.

Also, isn't it strange that userRoles is available to the newly created `userNewVersion` but roles are not?  After all, both userRoles and roles are configured to be FetchType.LAZY.  Without an EntityGraph to add the attribute node User_.userRoles, accessing userRoles in `userNewVersion` should throw a `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` -- but it doesn't.  How odd.

How can I merge entities, such as User, without losing their `EntityGraph` configurations while avoiding a second database hit (e.g. by doing a subsequent `EntityManager#find`)?

Comment: At the `updateEmail` method, which method throws the `LazyInitializationException`, the `iterator()` call ??

Comment: getRole() throws the LazyInitializationException.